# Unable to traverse props data from map and forEach function

Tags: reactjs, foreach, react-props, map-function, react-state

when I am logging the products, I am able to get the data in the console window but not able to traverse data from `array`  of object 'product'. I have tried **map** function as well as **forEach** function. Data is coming from the redux state via props and saved into the component state through `componentWillReceiveProps` where I have called `setState` function.

Please help in resolving this issue. Any Suggestions are Welcome!

Also when debugger breakpoint is added in code, I am not able to get data in the console window but when I remove debugger breakpoint from code, I am able to see data in the console window.

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchProduct} from '../actions/UploadAction';
import ProductCrudList from './ProductCrudList'

class ProductCrud extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            products:[],
            x:1,
            test:[{value:1},{value:2}]
        }
    }
    componentWillMount = () =>{
        this.props.fetchProduct();
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps=(nextProps)=>{
        if(this.props!=nextProps){
            this.setState((state)=>({products: nextProps.products}));
        }
    }
    render(){
        // debugger
        const {products, test, x} = this.state;
        console.log(products);
        products.forEach(p=>{
            console.log(p);
        })

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="">
                    <h2 style={{textAlign:'center', margin:'20px'}}>PRODUCTS</h2>
                    {   

                    }
                    {/* <ProductCrudList products={products} /> */}
                </div>
                {/* <h1>Working</h1> */}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state);
    return { 
        products: state.products.product
    }
}







const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    return {
        fetchProduct: () => {
            dispatch(fetchProduct())
        }
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProductCrud);
```

Added one image where you can see the console window where the array of objects display

[image]

Comment: What is your react version? I think you should use: `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()`

Comment: Check this website: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: Version of my react is '16.12.0'.

Comment: Tried 'UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()'.It's not working

Comment: try:
    `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        if(this.props.products.length !== nextProps.products.length){
            this.setState({products: [...nextProps.products]});
        }
    }`